# BroadCast Services and Notification's in Status Bar

Tags: android, notifications

Edit : I am going to ask my question in a different way again since i recieved any reply.

I think two problems caused by puting  alarm manager ,which the  broadcast receiver  is called by its pendingIntent, in Mainactivity . first whenever the app open it will be called then the notification shows up .
 secondly when the app is closed the notifications may not be called since they called in main activity ( or as they are braodcast they should be runned any way !!!!)
if so ,the question is where else can I put it ?

I am going to develop a TODO list as one feature in my application. I would like to notify user even if the app has not been running so I am using Broad cast services in which the service is called via my Main activity like below :

```
public void NOtifyMe( ArrayList<String> mArrayList)
{
        AlarmManager alarmMang = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        // ---get current date and time---

        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        calender.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

        Intent noteIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BroadCast.class);
        noteIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("ArrayList", mArrayList);//.putExtra("Cursor",c/*"ID", id*/);
        PendingIntent pendI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,
                noteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // // SET ALARM

        alarmMang.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendI);
        alarmMang.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendI);
```

and here is my Broad cast services code :

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> array = arg1.getStringArrayListExtra("ArrayList");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.Sali.todolist_final", "com.Sali.todolist_final.notifyService");
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ArrayList", array);
    arg0.startService(intent);

}
```

As you can see I am using array list , because it has not shown two notification in case there was two upcoming task. i was trying to do it first by calling the function as much as i had record in my Cursor.

here is the code in notifyService:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

        id = array.get(i);// .getLong(inId.getColumnIndex("_id"));//
                            // Long.valueOf(inId);
        g = Integer.parseInt(id);
        idtopass = Long.valueOf(id);
        counter = 0;
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(notifyService.this, TaskDetail.class);
        mainIntent.putExtra("id", idtopass);
        //mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                notifyService.this, g, mainIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        NotificationManager notificationManager;

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(notifyService.this)

        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("TO_Do")
                .setContentText("You Have Something To Do." + id);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent).setNumber(++counter);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(g, builder.build());

    }
```

Here I have two big problem :
first : it does not show the notification without app being run
second : as i set the proper flags , by clicking on the notification , it will appear again.
third (less important fot time being ) I dont like two have two notification icon in case there are 2 upcoming but i like by opening the window,user can see both . i know it is becouse i use Manager.notify in the for body ,but no other way for me in these case.if anyone has a solution for that as well.
I appriciate if someone can help me out here. It is really urgunt .

Comment: i dont see a onRecieve anywhere.

Comment: the code related to broadcast is inside OnReciever method. I edit it.

Comment: @user2511882 can you review my edited question ?